# JSON Data in javascript

Tags: json, chart.js

I would like to use json in chartJS. In first example I used

> ["0","76","32","88"]

and everything looks great.

Problem is in second example when I want to use JSON data as:

> var json =[{"wartosc":"0"},{"wartosc":"76"},{"wartosc":"32"},{"wartosc":"88"}];

In variable chartjsData i want to have data as ["0","76","32","88"] but it doesn't work.

```
var json =[{"wartosc":"0"},{"wartosc":"76"},{"wartosc":"32"},{"wartosc":"88"}];
var chartjsData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.lenght; i++) {
    chartjsData.push (json[i].wartosc);
}
var areaChartData = {
  labels: ["j","j","j","j"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Electronics",
      fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: ["0","76","32","88"]
    },
    {
      label: "Digital Goods",
      fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
      pointColor: "#3b8bba",
      pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
      data: chartjsData
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `.length`

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    chartjsData.push (json[i].wartosc);
}
```